# Fixed element jumping on scroll in iPad/iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, iphone

I have a fixed navigation on a webpage im building, the webpage is horizontal and the navigation links take you to X position along the horizontal timeline.

My issue is that on touch devices (iphone/ipad) my fixed navigation jumps horribly on scroll, as though its about to scroll with the content only it then remembers its fixed and goes back and does this repeatedly until the end of the scroll event.

Has anybody had this before?

**jQuery**

```
$('nav').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();     
    $('html, body').animate({'scrollLeft': 4000}, 1200);            
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nTg8e/1/

---

**EDIT**

This is only on iOS, not on android

Comment: what ios version are you on? fixed positioning is buggy on mobile, read this: http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/ and use at your own risk

Comment: I had the same issue once. I believe I changed the position to absolute and it got fixed

Comment: Setting it to absolute would mean it needs repositioning each time it moved though @KashifQureshi